# .NET 3.5 Control Charts w/ VS2010

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, charts

I've been using .NET 4.0 C# Windows Form Application utilizing the chart controls to render a chart on my form. I've recently had to switch to .NET 3.5 to use a reference that doesn't support 4.0. Now, I can’t use the chart controls for my application. I’ve downloaded and installed the recommended packages:

Microsoft Chart Controls for Microsoft .NET Framework 3.5
http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=14422

Microsoft Chart Controls Add-on for Microsoft Visual Studio 2008
http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=23903

But my problem is that I am using Visual Studio 2010, the add-on is only for vs2008.

I had to select 'Show All' on the toolbox in order to even see the chart option, but now it is disabled and when I attempt to click and drag I get a error icon as my mouse pointer. I tried to upload the image that shows the disabled chart, but SO wouldnt let me.

Is there any way that I can use the .Net 3.5 Chart Controls with VS2010?

Thanks, Bryan

Comment: Is the designer not working in 2010 ?

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft included a new version with the 4.0 framework its called System.web.ui.Datavisualization. You just need to add the namespace in 2010.

http://allen-conway-dotnet.blogspot.com/2010/07/updating-microsoft-charting-controls.html

Hope that helps!